# unresolved dependency: com.kyleu#jdub-async_2.11;1.0: not found

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

`plugin.sbt`: I define resolvers and plugins here.

```
logLevel := Level.Debug

resolvers += "JCenter repo" at "https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/"
resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "https://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"
resolvers += "mvnrepository" at "http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/"
resolvers += "Atlassian Releases" at "https://maven.atlassian.com/public/"
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.2")

addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-scalajs" % "0.6.3")

addSbtPlugin("com.vmunier" % "sbt-play-scalajs" % "0.2.6")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-gzip" % "1.0.0")
```

`build.sbt`: There are 3 projects in this file: shared, client and server. Client is a Scala.js application, server is a Play application and shared is a project which code is used in server and client projects.

```
import sbt.Project.projectToRef

lazy val clients = Seq(client)
lazy val scalaV = "2.11.6"

lazy val server = (project in file("server")).settings(
  scalaVersion := scalaV,
  scalaJSProjects := clients,
  pipelineStages := Seq(scalaJSProd, gzip),
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.vmunier" %% "play-scalajs-scripts" % "0.3.0",
    "org.webjars" % "jquery" % "1.11.1",
    "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.2.11",
    "com.github.benhutchison" %% "prickle" % "1.1.7",
    "com.kyleu" %% "jdub-async" % "1.0",
    specs2 % Test
  )
).enablePlugins(PlayScala).
  aggregate(clients.map(projectToRef): _*).
  dependsOn(exampleSharedJvm)

lazy val client = (project in file("client")).settings(
  scalaVersion := scalaV,
  persistLauncher := true,
  persistLauncher in Test := false,
  sourceMapsDirectories += exampleSharedJs.base / "..",
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.scala-js" %%% "scalajs-dom" % "0.8.0",
    "org.scala-js" %%% "scala-parser-combinators" % "1.0.2",
    "com.github.benhutchison" %%% "prickle" % "1.1.7"
  )
).enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin, ScalaJSPlay).
  dependsOn(exampleSharedJs)

lazy val shared = (crossProject.crossType(CrossType.Pure) in file("shared")).
  settings(scalaVersion := scalaV).
  jsConfigure(_ enablePlugins ScalaJSPlay).
  jsSettings(sourceMapsBase := baseDirectory.value / "..")

lazy val exampleSharedJvm = shared.jvm
lazy val exampleSharedJs = shared.js

onLoad in Global := (Command.process("project server", _: State)) compose (onLoad in Global).value
```

During compilation of server project I got an error: `unresolved dependency: com.kyleu#jdub-async_2.11;1.0: not found`. How to fix this issue?

Comment: You also need to add the resolvers to the project definitions if the dependency is not available on default repositories (everything in `plugin.sbt` is in a different scope than the stuff in your `build.sbt`).

Comment: Thank you! It solved my problem.